# MongoDB Multiple single indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a little unclear about indexing in `mongodb`.

Below I have a schema (in `mongoose`) for a `book` entry.  It has an `owner` and a `requestee`.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bookSchema = Schema({
    owner    : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true },
    title    : String,
    author   : String,
    image    : String,
    added    : Date,
    requestee: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true },
}, {collection: 'books'})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
```

What I want to do is to be able to query from both perspectives.

For the `owner` of the book:

`Book.find({owner: ObjectId(user._id)})`

This will be able to tell me if anyone is requesting the book

For the requestee:

`Book.find({requestee: ObjectId(requestee._id)})`

This will be able to tell me the requests a requestee has made.

I'm unclear about if what I have above is correct in terms of indexes. Can I have multiple single key indexes, or is what I'm doing scanning every document looking for a match?

Running the queries from the shell seem to work but again don't know if this is correct.

Comment: Here is little bit more about [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) and [indexes strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/). If you are looking ways to verify if the indexes are utilized,  you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/

Comment: @Veeram thanks for the `measure index use` doc, I think my assumption is correct based off what I'm seeing in the `explain("executionStats")`.  I think what you have is a perfectly acceptable answer. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `explain` on the query to view the index usage. Take a look at compound index as well if that is better for your use case.

More information here - 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/